# Is there a way to see the mnemonics of Bazel actions that are running?

Tags: bazel

(From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/XrtKLhH1bgI/B9xZn_aVAAAJ)

In our project that uses Bazel for building, I'm using the remote cache (`--spawn_strategy=remote`), and we are having to do some fine-tuning in order to turn off the cache for certain actions. For example, when we generate tar files, we don't want to use the remote cache, because (a) building tar files locally is just as fast as downloading them, and (b) some of our tar files can be really enormous.

So I'd like to have our .bazelrc files specify a different strategy for some actions, e.g. `--strategy=PackageTar=standalone`.

Here's the tricky part: In order to override the strategy, you need to know the mnemonic. E.g. for the `pkg_tar` rule, the relevant action has the mnemonic `PackageTar`. I found that in the bazel source. Some others are quite a bit trickier to figure out.

Is there any way I can get bazel to tell me the mnemonics of the actions it is executing? I looked into a variety of options, such as `--profile`, `--explain`, `--verbose_explanations`, `--subcommands`, but couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: Sorry about asking on your behalf, I realized that was a bad idea because now you don't own the question and don't get bounty for it.

Comment: Maybe rather tell people to ask again on Stackoverflow. While it is nice to ask for people, I'd rather have people learn to operate Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yep, agreed, I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with [`bazel aquery`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/aquery.html):

```
$ cat BUILD
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")

pkg_tar(
    name = "my_archive",
    srcs = ["hello.txt"],
)
```

```
$ bazel aquery :my_archive 2>/dev/null
action 'Writing file my_archive.args'
  Mnemonic: FileWrite
  Target: //:my_archive
  Configuration: k8-fastbuild
  ActionKey: 3dafce6be7ba0023b7eaae485085f977
  Inputs: []
  Outputs: [bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_archive.args]

action 'PackageTar my_archive.tar'
  Mnemonic: PackageTar
  Target: //:my_archive
  Configuration: k8-fastbuild
  ActionKey: 86bd5d0e112232cf0224fd0e3534f553
  Inputs: [<snip>]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_archive.tar]
  Command Line: (exec bazel-out/host/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/pkg/build_tar \
    --flagfile \
    bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_archive.args)
```

Note the `Mnemonic: PackageTar` line in the second action.

You can use the [`--output=textproto` option](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/aquery.html#aquery-options) to `bazel aquery` to
get machine-readable output.

You can also use queries like `bazel aquery 'outputs(".*\.tar", //...)'`
to narrow down the action graph; consult the `aquery` docs for more
details.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Bazel doesn't seem to report mnemonics anywhere.

You can find a list of available mnemonics by grepping for them in the source.

In Skylark rules:

```
cd <bazel_src_dir>
find -name '*.bzl' -not -path '*.git/*' -and -not -path '*/test/*' -type f | xargs grep 'mnemonic\s*='
```

In native rules:

```
cd <bazel_src_dir>
find src/main/java -name '*.java' -type f | xargs grep -A1 'String getMnemonic()'
```